# What is the URL for interacting with the Google API Interactive Console to test out queries and get JSON results?

Tags: api, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to find something from Google Cloud that is similar to the Interactive Spotify API Web [Console](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/).  Does anyone have any ideas that requires a sign into the Google account associated with the Google Cloud?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is available through the API reference pages: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/apis

On every method page, there's a form you can use on the right to test it out from the browser using your Google account.

For example, take a look at this page to list your Cloud SQL instances: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/list